# How do I set an optional argument in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've tried to research online, but no other questions were able to help me with my issue.

Here's my scenario.

I am making a mute command in discord.py.

I want the time to be optional, but if the time is not specified I want that argument to be part of the reason.

Clarification on what I mean:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: Member = None, time: int = None, *, reason = None):
    pass
```

Here, if `time` is None, then make it part of `reason`.

The bot will accept both of these:

`!mute @user 1h spam`
and
`!mute @user spam`

Is this possible?

Comment: " I want that argument to be part of the reason."  What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally wait asynchronously and then unmute the user:

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: typing.Optional[int]):
    await member.edit(mute=True)
    if time:
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        await member.edit(mute=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default argument:

```py
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time=None):
    if not time:
        # Mute indefinitely? do whatever you want
    else:
        # Mute for x amount of time
```

---

**References:**

- [Default arguments](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function-argument)
- [`typing.Optional`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional) - May be of interest to you.

Comment: No, I mean this. Basically when time doesn't exist, include that as part of the reason argument.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. My intention was to use the typing.Optional part.