# Discord.py Copy channel with permissions

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to make a CopyChannel(Permissions) command but something is wrong in my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def copych(ctx, *, channame, id: int = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if id == None:
        chan = ctx.channel
    else:
        chan = bot.get_channel(id=id)
    chan_perm = chan.overwrites
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=channame, overwrites=chan_perm)
```

There are no Errors and the channel is getting created but it doesn't overwrite the permissions.

I tried this here aswell but same Thing:

```py
@bot.command()
async def copych(ctx, *, channame, id: int = None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if id == None:
        chan = ctx.channel
    else:
        chan = bot.get_channel(id=id)
    chan_perm = chan.overwrites
    f = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=channame)
    await f.edit(overwrites=chan_perm)
```

Can someone tell me where the problem in the code is.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `*` would not work the way you're using it as [seen in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments). You may want to do this instead: `(ctx, id:int=None, *, channame)`

Comment: Ahh yeah thats not my code in my bot. I just wrote it rn and didnt mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really handy method to copy channels, `TextChannel.clone`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def copych(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    if channel is None:
        channel = ctx.channel

    await channel.clone()
```

Also instead of passing the channel ID when invoking the command you can use `TextChannelConverter` so it will also work when you mention the channel (`#channel`).

#### Reference:

- [`Channel.clone`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.clone)

Comment: Yeah I know there is a Channel.clone option but the problem is that I want to change the channels name(Yeah there is `await channel.edit(name)`) but I might want to tranfer the channel to another guild.

Comment: If you want to clone it with another name you can pass the name kwarg when cloning it, `await channel.close(name="new name")`

Comment: The name isn't the main problem. Its that I might want to tranfer the channel to another guild.(Idk if its possible to clone the channel to another guild with `channel.clone`.

Answer (score 0):

So here are some problems with the code you provided:

1. This line `async def copych(ctx, *, channame, id: int = None)`. As I mentioned in my previous comment [relating to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments), the way you use `*` is incorrect.
2. If you were to write a `string` instead of an `int` where you had written `id: int=None`, you would get a big error if it doesn't work.

So how can we combat these problems?

1. Once again referring to the docs, you would need to rearrange this line. As seen in the code below, you may rearrange it as I have shown. You only need one `int`, your id, as well as a channel name, your `channame` variable.
2. Using `typing.Optional`, you can make it so if the person executing the command does not specify a channel id, it refers to the current channel, `ctx.channel`. You can have a look at [another example of this being used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62440788/14420546).

```py
@bot.command()
async def copych(ctx, id: typing.Optional[int], *, channame="Channel"):
    if id == None:
        chan = ctx.channel
    else:
        chan = bot.get_channel(id=id)
    chan_perm = chan.overwrites
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name=channame, overwrites=chan_perm)
```